# Question about using apiGroup with RoleRef when creating ClusterRoleBinding

Tags: kubernetes

Here is a `ClusterRoleBinding` syntax that I found for creating Cluster role binding. Why does `apiGroup` needed to be specified when referring to role in `roleRef`? I have seen similar example in the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). What is the possible explanation?

### Example 1

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-secrets-global
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: manager # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: secret-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

### Example 2

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
```

Answer (score 1):

All Kubernetes resources have group, version, name, so an `apiGroup` field is required to identify a group.
For example, if you create your [Custom Resource Definition(CRD)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/), you need setting these fields.
below is the sample controller [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller/blob/master/artifacts/examples/crd.yaml):

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: foos.samplecontroller.k8s.io
spec:
  group: samplecontroller.k8s.io
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: Foo
    plural: foos
  scope: Namespaced
```

([ServiceAccount resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#serviceaccount-v1-core) is the core group. so I think ServiceAccount could be omitted a group field.)